# How to replace the automatic generated sql database in VS 2012 asp.net mvc 4 project?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have created an asp.net mvc 4 project, and now I want to deploy it to a internet provider. However it just provide me ftp upload method and only support SQL Server 2005.

Now I successfully upload and run the main project, but I need to create a SQL Server 2005 database to replace the automatically generated SQL Server 2012 version.

So I need create a new database and replace it. How to do it?

Comment: You may have some compatibility issues. Either way, do you have access to the generates db via SSMS?

Comment: Yes,I can open it in SQL Server, and see the data.@christiandev

Comment: finally, I found the best way is using SQL 2012 and don't worry about SQL 2005.